# Unable to display Octave figure in Atom on MacOS

Tags: octave, atom-editor, macos-mojave, platformio

I tried few different terminal implementations such as `terminal-plus` or `platformio-ide-terminal` on Atom (1.38.2) to run some Octave exercises. I noticed that the Octave shell runs normally until I try to plot anything. 
When I type `figure` into the shell no window pops up and no error or any other messages appear in the terminal. Yet everything runs OK in Mac (Mojave 10.14.5) own terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The popup is there but it is buried under Atom itself. If I call `figure(gcf)` instead of simply `figure` it brings the window to the foreground and displays above the IDE. If anyone has a better answer I'll be happy to accept

Comment: `figure` vs `figure(gcf)` shouldn't really make much difference ... out of curiosity, does the `shg` command work for you in this environment? If not, might be worth adding this info here: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?45943

Comment: (also, any particular reason why you're unhappy with the official GUI? it's a pretty decent GUI)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I tried it and on Mac there are a lot of wrong things with it starting with simple fact that you can't close the damn thing without actually `kill -9` it (twice)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou `shg` works if I have a hidden `figure` then it will bring it to the top. By itself (with no window) it seems to do nothing. BTW I'm self admittedly a complete Octave newbie

Comment: Some things are really annoying with Octave on Mac. For example I can't get out of `pause;` no matter which and how many times keys I push including <Enter>

Comment: Which octave are you on? 5.1.0? I don't use a mac, but there were some regression bugs to do with `pause` specifically in the latest release, so it may not be a mac thing (see [here](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?55854)). Apparently 5.1.0 was quite a major re-write. Re: `shg`, yes, that's what `shg` is supposed to do, it brings the "current" figure on the foreground (obviously if there isn't a current figure it won't do anything). Re: closing, does octave not exit normally when you type `exit` at the console?

Comment: Affirmative. I can't close Octave GUI (5.1.0) other than by `kill`ing it